# What happened inside if assign a primitive type value to a function's prototype?

Tags: javascript

```js
let ill = function() { this.a = 'legal'; };
ill.prototype = 1234;

let ins = new ill();

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(ins) === ill.prototype);
```

It prints `false`.

What happened inside if I insist to assign a depreciated type to function's prototype property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let ill = function() { this.a = 'legal'; };
ill.prototype = 1234;

let ins = new ill();

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(ins) === Object.prototype); //true
```

When calling a function with `new`, as part of the call an object is created and its prototype will be automatically set.

Normally, this would be the `prototype` property of the constructor but not necessarily. When the `prototype` property is not an object, then `Object.prototype` is used instead.

---

The details are found in [the specification, section 10.1.14 GetPrototypeFromConstructor](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-getprototypefromconstructor):

> 10.1.14 GetPrototypeFromConstructor ( *constructor*, *intrinsicDefaultProto* )
>
> The abstract operation GetPrototypeFromConstructor takes arguments *constructor* (a function object)  and *intrinsicDefaultProto* (a String) and returns either a normal completion containing an Object or an abrupt completion. It determines the [[Prototype]] value that should be used to create an object corresponding to a specific constructor. The value is retrieved from the constructor's "**prototype**" property, if it exists. Otherwise the intrinsic named by *intrinsicDefaultProto* is used for [[Prototype]]. It performs the following steps when called:
>
> 1. Assert: *intrinsicDefaultProto* is this specification's name of an intrinsic object. The corresponding object must be an intrinsic that is intended to be used as the [[Prototype]] value of an object.
> 2. Let *proto* be ? Get(*constructor*, "**prototype**").
> 3. If Type(*proto*) is not Object, then
>
>    a. Let *realm* be ? GetFunctionRealm(*constructor*).
>
>    b. Set *proto* to *realm*'s intrinsic object named *intrinsicDefaultProto*.
> 4. Return *proto*.

In particular it is part of step 3. - the prototype if `ill` is not an object but a primitive, therefore, the intrinsic default prototype is used and that is set as `"%Object.prototype%"` as defined in [section 10.2.2 [[Construct]]](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-createdynamicfunction) which defines the semantics of calling a function as a constructor:

> 10.2.2 [[Construct]] ( *argumentsList*, *newTarget* )
>
> The [[Construct]] internal method of an ECMAScript function object *F* takes arguments *argumentsList* (a List of ECMAScript language values) and *newTarget* (a constructor) and returns either a normal completion containing an Object or a throw completion. It performs the following steps when called:
>
> 1. Let *callerContext* be the running execution context.
> 2. Let *kind* be *F*.[[ConstructorKind]].
> 3. If *kind* is base, then
>
>    a. Let *thisArgument* be ? OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor(*newTarget*, "**%Object.prototype%**").
>
> [...]